# CakePHP - how to push array in Session?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, cakephp

If I have the following,

```
$this->Session->write('ScoreCardCriteria', 'test');
```

And want to add another item to ScoreCardCriteria as an array of items, how would I do so?

With regular PHP, It would be something like

```
$_SESSION['ScoreCardCriteria'][] = 'test';
```

I came up with this:

```
    $new_array = array_merge((array)$this->Session->read('ScoreCardCriteria'), array('test'));
    $this->Session->write('ScoreCardCriteria', $new_array);
```

But I'd love it if there was a more "cake" way to do it.

Comment: The method I came up with didn't quite work. It just overwrote all the values...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this:

```
$this->Session->write('ScoreCardCriteria', array( 'test' ) );
```

And then:

```
$data = $this->Session->read('ScoreCardCriteria');
$data[] = 'test';
$this->Session->write('ScoreCardCriteria', $data);
```

However, to be quite honest, CakePHP uses the $_SESSION object internally and just overrides the default session handlers. The only thing `->write` does is parse a dot notated set path (which would look like `foo.bar.x`) which you are not doing. And echo debug information if you are watching particular values. It shouldn't hurt if you modify `$_SESSION` directly.

Comment: Anyone know why this was voted down? It is almost the same as the other answer that was posted 7 minutes later and not voted down.

Comment: Not sure... it's what I ended up doing and worked great. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Since I complained several people up-voted it anyway :). I was just curious what I did wrong to deserve a -1

Comment: Realise this was a long time ago but the answer given about having to use `$_SESSION` directly still seems valid. Basically Cake 3.x cannot handle arrays inside its native session methods. I've posted an explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39491196/cakephp-3-how-to-make-session-array/#48560949

Answer (score 2):

You need to read the session data and then merge it with your data to be appended. You should also check if the session data exists before doing so:

```
if ($this->Session->check('ScoreCardCriteria')) {
    $this->Session->write('ScoreCardCriteria', am(
       $this->Session->read('ScoreCardCriteria'),
       array('test')
    ));
} else {
    $this->Session->write('ScoreCardCriteria', array('test'));
}
```

Hope that helps.