# Cakephp 3 How to make session array

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to write session in controller. My structure is

```
$_SESSION['a'][0] = 1;
$_SESSION['a'][1] = 2;
$_SESSION['a'][2] = 3;
```

And I am trying this

```
Configure::write('Session', ['a' =>'1'])
```

But it is not working. How do this in cakephp 3 way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To write variable in Session in CakePHP 3 you need to write following code :

```
$this->request->session()->write('Your Key',Your_array);
```

To know more information you can visit here :

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

To make things perfectly clear:

```
// code writing array to session
$a = [ "abc" => "word", "123" => 42, "?" => $b ];
$a["more"] = "if you need to add";
$a[] = "whatever";
$this->request->session()->write( 'my_array', $a );
// code reading array from session
$recall = $this->request->session()->read( 'my_array' );
debug( sprintf( "What's the word? [%s]", $recall["abc"] ) );
```

Comment: Its working but when I append any other value it overwrite insted of add

Comment: To write you need to read the array from session and push the new value to array and than again write to the session for same key. Because as per CakePHP 3 documentation value will be overwrite if you pass same key

Comment: If this works for you than do not forgot to accept the answer

Comment: It is not possible to do this in CakePHP 3.x. I've posted an answer explaining why. **This answer is wrong**.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use

```
$session->write([
  'key1' => 'blue',
  'key2' => 'green',
]);
```

I am refering to

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#reading-writing-session-data

Comment: There is no session component anymore in CakePHP 3.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as he wants to create *an array*, not separate keys. `key1` and `key2` are individually named keys. What if you want to do it as an array where the name is `a[]`? You cannot do this in CakePHP 3.x. I've posted an explanation as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is that this cannot be done in CakePHP 3.x**

In vanilla PHP, it's possible to do this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['a'][0] = 1;
    $_SESSION['a'][1] = 2;
    $_SESSION['a'][2] = 3;
    var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Which will output:

```
array(1) { 
    ["a"]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> int(1) 
        [1]=> int(2) 
        [2]=> int(3) 
    } 
}
```

This is correct, and what *should* happen.

In CakePHP, you cannot specify arrays in the session key. For example:

```
$this->request->session()->write('a[]', 1);
$this->request->session()->write('a[]', 2);
$this->request->session()->write('a[]', 3);
```

Will not work.

If you remove the `[]` **the value will get overwritten**. For example:

```
$this->request->session()->write('a', 1);
$this->request->session()->write('a', 2);
$this->request->session()->write('a', 3);
```

The value of `$this->request->session()->read('a')` would be `3`. The values `1` and `2` have been overwritten. Again, this is to be expected because you're overwriting the key `a` each time. The equivalent vanilla PHP for this is:

```
$_SESSION['a'] = 1;
$_SESSION['a'] = 2;
$_SESSION['a'] = 3;
```

Due to the lack of an indexed array, `$_SESSION['a']` gets overwritten each time. This is normal behaviour. It needs to have the indexes (e.g. `['a'][0], ['a'][1], ...`) to work!

The other answers where they have given things like `key1` and `key2` are not appropriate. Because there are many situations where you want everything contained within an indexed array. Generating separate key names is wrong for this type of scenario.

Comment: You got caught up in using the CakePHP session-interface the same way as in vanilla PHP - you can write an array to a specific key and retrieve that array again, as an array, via that key as desribed in the accepted answer

Comment: @flowtron you're completely wrong. The accepted answer given on this is incorrect and if you'd actually tested it with a CakePHP 3 installation you'd see why. The accepted answer writes to an array key called `'Your Key'` so if you write to it again it'll overwrite whatever value is in that key. This is exactly the point that the question was addressing and it cannot be done using CakePHP's session syntax whereas it can with vanilla PHP. If you're going to comment then please test your work before commenting. If you have a workaround then post it as an answer.

Comment: I /did/ .. you still do not seem to understand the way to work with the session in CakePHP, the accepted answer may not be totally clear either, but it shows the way to do it. If you have an array in $a and you $this->request->session()->write( 'my_array', $a ) you can later retrieve the entire array via the key 'my_array' .. where you append items to the array via the $a[] push method is irrelevant .. in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

My edit of the accepted answer was rejected, so I present the - seemingly necessary - **explicit** code example, for the benefit of [@Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6565681/andy) and others.

```
// code to write to session
$a = [ 0 => "zero", 1 => "one", 2 => "two"  ];
$a[] = "three";
$this->request->session()->write( 'my_array', $a );

// code to read from session
$z = $this->request->session()->read( 'my_array' );
debug( $a[3] ); // outputs "three"
```